# Help me with this integration please.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I do not have the symbols in my mobile keyboard, so I will try to explain it here with the available ones.
$$\int_{-π}^π \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+a^x} \,\mathrm{d}x. \quad  a>0$$

I am still trying.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: please explain what you have tried

Comment: what makes you sure there is an analytic answer?

Comment: I have tried with a^x=z and a^x=e^z, but It's becoming lengthy with no improvement. I am not that good in math though. I am unable to relate sin x and 1+a^x somehow. Not sure about if analytic or not.

Comment: The answer seems to be $\pi/2$, which I imagine is related to the integral $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1+a^x}dx = \pi$$ and using $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$ in the numerator. 

If you can show that
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2 x}{1+a^x}dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos^2 x}{1+a^x}dx$$ then you are done. Not exactly sure how to proceed form there though.

Comment: Thank you whpowell96. You made me think in another direction. I got the answer. I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $u=-x$.

\begin{align*}
\int_{-π}^π \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+a^x}dx&=-\int_\pi^{-\pi}\frac{\sin^2(-u)}{1+a^{-u}}du\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{a^u\sin^2u}{a^{u}+1}du\\
\end{align*}

So,

\begin{align*}
\int_{-π}^π \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+a^x}dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-π}^π\left[\frac{\sin^2 x}{1+a^x}+\frac{a^x\sin^2 x}{1+a^x}\right]dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-π}^π\sin^2xdx
\end{align*}

Comment: I was typing this actually. Thank you.

Comment: @CYAries ... How did the last term cone out ...?

Comment: The integrands of the two integrals are exactly the same